# Genetic algorithm doesn't seem to optimise

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, convergence

I have a simple problem to test my GA on but it doesn't seem to converge or converges to a seemingly random value. I've seen other posts with similar issues and have amended the issues that are present in the ones I've seen (if relevant) but it still doesn't seem to converge. I'm unsure whether this is just needing to play about with variables like the mutation rate etc. or whether I've done something wrong.
The problem it's trying to optimise is fairly simple:
Find the maximum of the function f(x) = xsin(10πx)+1 in the range -1 < x < 2. From plotting the graph of f(x) I know that the result should be f(x=1.8505) = 2.8503.

Code:

```
    #####################################################################################################
################################# Genetic Algorithm Class (Attempt) #################################
#####################################################################################################

#####################################################################################################
########################################## Relevant Imports ##########################################
#####################################################################################################

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from qutip import *

class GA:
    
    
#####################################################################################################
################################## Fitness and Selection Function ###################################
############# Detects how well the pulse sequence works and selects the top x sequences #############
#####################################################################################################

    def fitness(self, population):
        
        n = np.linspace(0,len(population)-1,len(population)) # creates list for indices for loop
        
        f = np.zeros(int(len(n))) # defines empty array for fitness values
        
        # runs a loop to obtain the fitness values of all members in the population and add each 
        # fitness for each population to array f
        for i in n:
            
            
            f[int(i)] = population[int(i)]*np.sin(10*np.pi*population[int(i)])+1
        
        # finds the total fitness to obtain percentage values to allow for biased selection
        total_f = sum(f)
        percentage_f = [x + abs(min(f)) for x in f]
        percentage_f = [x/sum(percentage_f) for x in percentage_f]
        
        return [f, percentage_f]
    
#####################################################################################################
############################################ Cross Over #############################################
################## "Breeds" two ideal solutions to try and obtain a better solution #################
#####################################################################################################

    def crossover(self,a,b):
        
        new_a = (a+b)/2
        
        return new_a 
    
#####################################################################################################
############################################### Mutate ###############################################
########################################## Mutates a member ##########################################
#####################################################################################################    
    def mutate(self,a, mutationrate):
        
        
        check = np.random.choice(['mutate','dont mutate'], 1, p = [mutationrate,1-mutationrate])
        
        if check == 'mutate':
            new_a = 0
            while new_a < -1 or new_a > 2:
                new_a = a + random.uniform(-1,1)
                
            return new_a
        else:
            return a
        
        return
    
#####################################################################################################
######################################### Create New Member #########################################
################################ Creates a new random pulse sequence ################################
#####################################################################################################

    def create_new_member(self,min_val = -1, max_val = 2):
        
        member = random.uniform(min_val,max_val)
        
        return member

    
#####################################################################################################
##################################### Create Initial Population #####################################
################################ Creates an initial array of members ################################
#####################################################################################################

    def create_initial_population(self,size):
        
        population = [] # define empty population array
        
        #loops over desired size to append each member into the population array
        for i in range(0,size): 
            
            population.append(self.create_new_member())
        
        return population

#####################################################################################################
###################################### Create Next Generation #######################################
####################### Runs a loop to create a number of new pulse sequences #######################
#####################################################################################################

    def create_next_generation(self, population, percentage_f, size):
        
        #################################### Biased selection ####################################
        
        # selects a number of members (defined by input size) in the population, taking
        # into consideration the probability distribution percentage_f where each index of 
        # the probability distribution corresponds to the same indexed member in the population
        # The key word replace defines whether, once a member is chosen, it is removed or kept
        # in for the next choice
        new_population = np.random.choice(population, size, p=percentage_f, replace = True)                 
        
        return new_population
    
#####################################################################################################
############################################### Main ################################################
##################################### Main body of the program ######################################
#####################################################################################################

    def main(self, number_of_iterations, size, mutations, crossovers):
        
        bestf = []
        avgf = []
        
        # creates the initial population
        population = self.create_initial_population(size)
        
        # creates interger list to loop over for the number of desired iterations
        generations = np.linspace(1, number_of_iterations, number_of_iterations)
        
        ################################ Start of optimisation loop ################################
        for i in generations:
            
            
            p = np.linspace(1, crossovers, crossovers)
            index_p = np.linspace(0,len(population)-1,len(population))  # redefines index array to
                                                                        # to include all members again            
            for k in p:
                # Selects 2 random index values for the population to crossover and removes them
                # from the index array
                r1 = random.choice(index_p)
                np.delete(index_p,int(r1))
                r2 = random.choice(index_p)
                np.delete(index_p,int(r1))
                
                children = self.crossover(population[int(r1)], population[int(r2)]) # creates the children
                                                                          # members
                population = np.hstack((population,children)) # extends the child members into the population array
            
            
            
            ######### Mutates a random member for the number of times defined by mutations ########
            m = np.linspace(1, len(population), len(population))        # iterations for number of mutations
            index_p = np.linspace(0,len(population)-1,len(population)) # index values of population
            mutationrate = 1/len(population)
            for j in m:
                
                r1 = random.choice(index_p) # chooses random index in population to mutate
                population[int(r1)] = self.mutate(population[int(r1)],mutationrate) # mutates member in population at
                                                             # index r1                
                np.delete(index_p,int(r1)) # removes index r1 from index array to prevent the same member
                                # being mutated twice
            
            [f, percentage_f] = self.fitness(population) # evaluates the fitness of each member in 
                                                         # the population
                        
            bestf.append(max(f))
            avgf.append(np.mean(f))
            
            # Overwrites the population array by creating the next generation
            population = self.create_next_generation(population, percentage_f, size)
        
        plt.plot(generations,bestf)
        plt.plot(generations,avgf)
        plt.title('Final Plot')
        plt.xlabel('Generation')
        plt.ylabel('Y-value (fitness)')
        plt.savefig('Final plot.png')
        plt.show()
        
        return
```

A couple of the plots for clarity:

[image]
[image]

edit: Forgot to put on the legend, in each graph the orange line represents the average fitness of the population and the blue line represents the fitness for the best member for each generation.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, it is better to use an exact solution i.e just check all the possible values of x and return your solution.

Genetic algorithms are designed for large sized problems. The aim of using genetic algorithms is to reduce the number of solutions you evaluate in those large problems where evaluating all possible solutions is unrealistic.